# ExcelJs dynamic hyperlinks not routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, exceljs

I created a workbook in Exceljs and added some worksheets dynamically do them. Basically I have a master worksheet that is the first thing you see when you open it up. However, I've also created `player profiles` for each person in my initial table. I'm trying to link them up with this piece of code.

```
    team.forEach((e, index) => {
      console.log(`--- Writing ${e.name} ---`)

      worksheet.addRow({
        teamName: e.teamName,
        name: e.name,
        weight: e.weight,
        wins: e.wins,
        losses: e.losses,
        profile: {
          text: 'This Profile',
          hyperlink: `${e.name}`
        }
      })
```

And unfortunately, this is just showing the text `This Profile` and it isn't able to be clicked on. Each of my worksheets are just the names of the people apart of the team. I am not sure if there is special syntax I need to add.

Here is how I am naming my workbook. I see all of the player profiles being created, just the hyperlinks aren't working.

```
async function writePlayerProfile(e, workbook) {
  let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(`${e.name}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good but there is an issue in excel js maybe this will help you

[hyperlink issue excel js](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1274)

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your hyperlink is wrong because the data is `{e.name}` that doesn't seem to have valid URL format.

Comment: What's a valid URL format for internal sheets within a workbook? I just assumed that it would be the name of the sheet would be how you navigated around. I didn't know it needed to be a specific format.